# How to sort a String array

Tags: java, sorting

I have an `String` array called `myArray` (for the sake of argument, let's just say it contains words from a story). I want to pass this array to a method that will sort them alphabetically and analyze the words. I've looked this up on SO and many people have suggested for this scenario to use `java.util.Arrays.sort(myArray)`. So I used this line in my method, passed in `myArray`, and performed calculations on it, etc etc.

However, it recently came to my attention that this will permanently sort `myArray.` That is, the array will still be sorted after I come out of the method. Is there a way for me to only sort the array within the scope of the method?

Example code:

```
public static double uniqueWords(String[] doc1) {

    java.util.Arrays.sort(doc1)

    ... // count up the number of unique words in this array

    return COUNT_OF_UNIQUE_WORDS;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] document;
    ... // put values in the array
    System.out.println(uniqueWords(document));
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(document));   // here the array will still be sorted, which I DON'T want
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String temp[] = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(doc1,doc1.length);
java.util.Arrays.sort(temp);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Make a copy of the array, sort that copy and use the same.**

```
  String [] sortedDocuments = new Sting[document.length];
  Systems.arraycopy(document, 0, sortedDocuments , 0, document.length);
  Arrays.sort(sortedDocuments );
```

or

```
  String [] sortedDocuments = Arrays.copyOf(document, document.length);
  Arrays.sort(sortedDocuments );
```

Use the `sortedDocuments` array with-in your method. Your original array `document` is left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to count unique words, better use the following code. There's no need to sort your array to count unique elements.

```
public int countUniqueElements(Object[] array) {
    return new HashSet(Arrays.asList(array)).size();
}
```

Comment: yeah I knew that. I actually do more things that find unique words, I just wanted something simple to type so I wouldn't have to include ALL of my code haha. It was the first thing to come to mind. But thanks!